# Does this code mean the model trains 10 epochs?

Tags: terminology

Here is an implementation for Perceptron

```
class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self, eta=.1, n_iter=10, model_w=[.0, .0], model_b=.0):
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.model_w = model_w
        self.model_b = model_b

    def predict(self, x):
        if np.dot(self.model_w, x) + self.model_b >= 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1

    def update_weights(self, idx, model_w, model_b):
        w = model_w
        b = model_b
        w += self.eta * y_train[idx] * x_train[idx]
        b += self.eta * y_train[idx]
        return w, b

    def fit(self, x, y):
        if len(x) != len(y):
            print('error')
            return False
        for i in range(self.n_iter):
            for idx in range(len(x)):
                if y[idx] != self.predict(x[idx]):
                    self.model_w, self.model_b = self.update_weights(idx,
                                            self.model_w, self.model_b)
```

Does this code

```
Perceptron(eta=.1, n_iter=10)
```

mean the model trains 10 epochs?

Comment: Questions about programming issues are generally off-topic here. It seems to me that this is one of those questions. Please, take a look at https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details about our scope.

Comment: @nbro Thanks for the comments. This is not about programming issues. The code works well. This is about terminology. The code is an easy-to-understand example of the algorithm.

Comment: yes that's 10 epochs, `for idx` makes 1 epoch, `for i` makes 10 epochs